# Alert message box doesn't display

Tags: php

I have following lines of code for insert record. I want to display an alert message box saying record added successfully. However, record inserted successfully but the message box doesn't display and opens the main.php file directly. How can I display the message as well as open the main.php

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, address, mobile, 
email) VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$mobile', '$email');
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
  echo '<script>alert("Record added successfully")</script>';
  header("location: main.php");
      exit();
 } else{
     echo "No record added. Something wrong.";
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The code you posted looks like PHP so it would be helpful if you could give your question a PHP tag. It creates Javascript, so give it a Javascript tag too. Alert, Message and Box are not the sort of tags people will be looking for so they may miss your message. Your code as posted seems to be missing a string terminator so best to check that. The problem is one of timing - what happens when. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the PHP given in the question we can see that an alert statement is echoed but it is immediately followed by a call to header.  This is executed on the server and will be executed straight away. This is the behaviour reported in the question (goes straight to main.php without the alert being seen).

What is needed is for the user to see the alert and the redirect to main to happen only when they are ready to do so (ie responded to the alert).

The redirect therefore needs to be done on the client side.
Change:

```
echo '<script>alert("Record added successfully")</script>';
header("location: main.php");
```

to:

```
echo '<script>
      alert("Record added successfully");
      window.location="main.php";
</script>';
```

The user should then see the alert, and their system will wait for them to respond to it before relocating to main.php